# Why comparison operator not working properly and Block of operator 'ne' is working

Tags: perl, conditional-operator

I have some strings I am taking from the command line as an argument, I required to run the block, if particular argument has been passed or else it shows the print statement and exit.

I am using two blocks where in first one I am using `ne` operator to check if strings is not equal to desired strings then exiting the program and `eq` operator to check if string passed is equal then execute the code.

Below is my code snippet:

```
 my $number_args = $ #ARGV + 1;
 if ($number_args ne 2) {
         print "Usage: perl testAutomation.pl <ExcelSheetName.xlsx> <Production/Development/All>.\n";
         exit;
 }
 my $tstRunSheet = $ARGV[0];
 my $tstRunType = $ARGV[1];

 if ($tstRunType ne 'Development' || $tstRunType ne 'Production' || $tstRunType ne 'All') {
         print "Usage: perl testAutomation.pl <ExcelSheetName.xlsx> <Production/Development/All>.\n";
         exit;
 }
 elsif($tstRunType eq 'Development' || $tstRunType eq 'Production') {
         ($result1, $result2, $result3, $result4, $result5, $result6, $result7, $result8) = & getXlxsDetails($tstRunSheet, $tstRunType);
 }
```

When I am giving proper string as required in my `elsif` block still it is running the `if` block.

Output: [image: Output]

Comment: Next time, please post your inputs/outputs as text rather than screenshots.

Comment: Don't do this: `$ #ARGV` and `& getXlxsDetails(`. These are technically syntax errors. I don't know what the Perl interpreter makes of those weird separated sigils, but even if it works, it is a bad thing, and you should not do it. It is `$#ARGV` for the last index of the array, and `&getXlxsDetails(` with no space.

Answer (score 6):

The issue comes from this line:

```
if ($tstRunType ne 'Development' || $tstRunType ne 'Production' || $tstRunType ne 'All') {
```

This condition is always true: if `$tstRunType` is `Development`, then it's not `Production`, and `$tstRunType ne 'Production'` returns true (and similarly for all possible values of `$tstRunType`).
Instead, you should write:

```
if ($tstRunType ne 'Development' && $tstRunType ne 'Production' && $tstRunType ne 'All') {
```

Then, if `$tstRunType` is one of `Development`, `Production` or `All`, the corresponding `ne` test will return false, making the whole condition false.

---

You could also write this condition as:

```
my @run_types = qw(Development Production All);
if (!grep { $tstRunType eq $_ } @run_types) { ...
```

This way, you don't have to repeat 3 times a similar test and you can easily add new run types.

Or, using a regex to have a slightly more compact test:

```
if ($tstRunType !~ /^(Development|Production|All)$/) {
```

---

Also, note that `my $number_args = $#ARGV + 1;` can be written simply as `my $number_args = @ARGV;`.

Comment: If i want to use regex for both, I meant for my 'eq' conditon also, what we should write on the place of !~.

Comment: @LalitKumarSingh Do you mean that you want to write `$tstRunType eq 'Development' || $tstRunType eq 'Production'` with a regex? Then simply `$tstRunType =~ /^(Development|Production)$/`

Comment: yes I meant that, Thanks

Comment: @LalitKumarSingh By the way, I see that you haven't accepted any of the answers provided to your other questions so far (in particular, you have 2 questions with positively-scored answers that you didn't accept). See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and consider accepting the answers that solved your questions.

Comment: I am very new to SO, I used to upvote the answers sir, if this is the way to accept then I am accepting. I did the same for this question, else sir pls guide me for the same.

Comment: also sir, can you please tell when I call all condition elsif($tstRunType =~ /^(All)$/){
 for(my $i=0;$i<2;$i++){
  if($i==0){
   $tstRunType = 'Development';
   ($result1,$result2,$result3,$result4,$result5,$result6,$result7,$result8)=&getXlxsDetails($tstRunSheet,$tstRunType);
   }
   elsif($i==1){
    $tstRunType ='Production';
    ($result1,$result2,$result3,$result4,$result5,$result6,$result7,$result8)=&getXlxsDetails($tstRunSheet,$tstRunType);
    }
  }
} it is only running one time, i dont know whats wrong, pls help. I wanted to run both Production as well as Development.

Comment: @LalitKumarSingh Under the "accept" button, there is a gray checkmark that you can click to mark the answer as "accepted" (which basically signifies that this answer solved your issue). (there is no obligation to accept question though)

Comment: @LalitKumarSingh Regarding your other question... I'm not sure what's wrong. The use of the loop looks very weird. You could ask a new question about that. BUT, you've already asked quite a lot of questions in the past 2 days, and I think that you should spend a bit more time reading a Perl tutorial before asking. We are happy to help, but, at the same time, we don't really want to do your job for you...

Comment: @Dada Also on that last thing, it is `$#ARGV`, not `$ #ARGV`. No sense in perpetuating an error.

Comment: @TLP Good point, thanks. I've never written that with a space, but since OP posted it, I assumed that it was working; silly of me -_-'

Answer (score 4):

Dada has given you the correct answer: Your logic is flawed.

```
my $x = 1;
if ($x != 0 || $x != 1)    # will always be true, no matter what $x is, because 0 != 1
```

But more than that, I think your structure is wrong. You should not begin by gathering all the valid options and check for lack of them. Go through and check all the options, and then have as a default behaviour the lack of a valid option. For example:

```perl
if ($type eq "Dev") {
    print "Dev things\n";
} elsif ($type eq "Prod") {
    print "Prod things\n";
} elsif ($type eq "All") {
    print "All things\n";
} else {
    print "Usage: ...:";
    exit;
}
```

Another design detail is your repetition of the usage message. You can put that in a sub.

```perl
sub usage {
    print "Usage: $0 <excel> <keywd>";
    exit;
}
```

For quick and easy use:

```
usage() if @ARGV != 2;
```

Note that you should not use `ne` for numerical comparisons. Study [perldoc perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Equality-Operators) to learn more. In your case, `ne` will try to cast the numbers `2` to a string, `"2"` and then perform `"2" ne "2"`. A common mistake when confusing these operators is this:

```
my $word = "foo";
if ($word == "bar") {
    print "$word == 'bar'\n";
}
```

This will give us the very confusing output:

```
foo == 'bar'
```

Which is explained when we activate `use warnings`:

```
Argument "bar" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at bar.pl line 3.
Argument "foo" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at bar.pl line 3.
foo == 'bar'
```

What happens? Well, `==` assumes its both arguments are numbers, so it tries to cast the strings `"foo"` and `"bar"` to numbers. Which it fails to do, since neither of the strings begin with a number, or look like a number. So they are cast to `0`, numerical zero. And `0 == 0` is true.

So what is wrong with using `ne` if it works? Well, in this case it works, but it can fail for comparisons such as `" 2" eq "2"`, `2 eq "2.0"`, etc. Cases where the string values are different, even though the numerical values are the same.

Also note that you could use a call table to reduce the size of your if-structure.

```perl
my %calls = ( 
    Dev     => "Dev things\n",
    Prod    => "Prod things\n",
    All     => "All things\n"
);

if (! exists $calls{$type}) {
    usage();          # this call does not exist
}
print $calls{$type};
```

Such a call table could also contain code.

```perl
my ($sheet, $type)  = @ARGV;
my $debug           = 0;    # default off
my $logging         = 0;    # default off

my %calls = ( 
    Dev     => sub { print "Dev things\n"; $debug = 1 },
    Prod    => sub { print "Prod things\n"; $logging = 1; },
    All     => sub { print "All things\n"; }
);

if (! exists $calls{$type}) {
    usage();
}
$calls{$type}->();
```

Finally, note that checking args case sensitively might not be user friendly. Do you really want someone who uses the arg `dev` to fail because it requires `Dev`? You can solve this by coercing the input to lower case:

```perl
$type = lc($type);         # lower case
if ($type eq "dev") {      # check lower case
```

Or use a regex with `/i` modifier.

```perl
if ($type =~ /dev/i) {     # matches any case
```